# TTArtisan 25mm f2 lens focus ring adjustment

Tags: lens, focus

The lens: https://www.ttartisan.com/?list_10/152.html
I bought this lens now twice for my Fuji X-E1, and both lenses had identical infinity focus issue. Infinity mark is not focussed, I have to move slightly back to 3m. I read and saw some YouTube posts and blogs that you can adjust the focus ring by unscrewing the 3 screws on the focus ring, and then I can adjust it, but unscrewing those screws did nothing. The focus ring still moves the lens core up and down, so the screws are there just for the looks I guess? Even when asked on the Amazon page I bought it, there was a reply to adjust the ring by doing these steps, but it doesn't work.

Anyone else had this issue with this specific lens and could you fix it? I already followed the steps here https://yukosteel.wordpress.com/2018/06/14/calibrating-focus-lens-with-bolts-on-focus-ring/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dissembling the entire lens, I found out why just unscrewing the 3 screws on the focus ring did not losen the ring and I could not freely move it. As I said, this also was the case for the previous one I bought. Apparently, in manufacturing, they add a drop of super glue between the focus ring, and the ring that normally the screw is tightened on. After removing all the hardened glue, the focus ring was freely moving, and after aligning every part and assembling the entire lens, I was finally able to adjust the focus to infinity, then loosening the focus ring screws, aligning infinity mark, and tightening the ring. Now I can quickly focus infinity perfectly.

[image]